# mysql to Criteria() in symfony 1.4.9

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I have the following  complex query in mySQL

```
SELECT courseId,courseName
FROM course WHERE courseId NOT IN (SELECT courseId FROM coursestaken NATURAL JOIN student WHERE grade >= 60 AND studentId =2) 
AND
courseId NOT IN (SELECT courseId FROM stable WHERE studentId = 2 )
AND
courseId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT courseId FROM prerequisites 
WHERE
prereqId NOT IN (SELECT courseId FROM coursestaken NATURAL JOIN student WHERE grade >= 60 AND studentId =2  )) ;
```

Can someone help me convert this to a Criteria() query in Propel?

Comment: As well try to avoid too many subqueries, generally it leads to performance problems.

Answer (score 4):

Try using prepare function in propel like below

```
    $con=Propel::getConnection();
            $obj = $con->prepare("SELECT courseId,courseName
FROM course WHERE courseId NOT IN (SELECT courseId FROM coursestaken NATURAL JOIN student WHERE grade >= 60 AND studentId =2) 
AND
courseId NOT IN (SELECT courseId FROM stable WHERE studentId = 2 )
AND
courseId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT courseId FROM prerequisites 
WHERE
prereqId NOT IN (SELECT courseId FROM coursestaken NATURAL JOIN student WHERE grade >= 60 AND studentId =2  )) ");
            $obj->execute();
            $resultset = $obj->fetchAll();
```

Comment: +1 for this. Don't try and create Criteria statements when SQL is complex - especially when you're not returning hydrated object(s). Use this link as your guide for using Propel properly: http://propel.posterous.com/how-can-i-write-this-query-using-an-orm